# Dawah of prophet Muhammad peace be upon him in Mecca

Tags: practical-islam

The most important aspect of Islam is tawheed or oneness of Allah. I want to know what are the things that prophet Muhammad peace be upon him said during his Meccan period to the disbelievers. Most of the people were part disbelievers in Allah taala because they new that Allah was the greatest God and the god of the house.

Comment: The message of the Prophet to the people of Mecca is present in the Quran, especially in the Meccan Surahs and verses. It is impractical to list everything in an answer. Please ask a clear and specific question and do trivial research on your own.